# "Zoom" into centered div on smaller screens

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm working on a page where I have a single div on screen (with a bunch of stuff inside it) that needs to be set to a specific height and width.

On desktop and tablets it looks great.

But get it on a tiny phone and it looks itty-bitty.

http://note.io/1mSFYDM

I'm looking for a way to 'zoom' into the div without having to adjust my css on a phone automatically when the page loads.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Are you using percentage widths and heights?

Comment: No, it's pixels. Which, I suppose is a bad way to do it, but at this point it'd be a big hassle to go back and rewrite everything with percentages so I'm looking for a way to avoid that.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting this in your `<head>` tag:
    `<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, width=device-width, height=device-height, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />`

Comment: Hmm, that didn't work as-is: http://note.io/1mSHOo0 But I'll tweak with the numbers and see if I can get it to play nicely. Thanks :)

Comment: Please explain your code. It seems to have unneccesary side effects (user-scalable=no?)